# Post apocalyptic movie about a boy who travels through desert with a duckling in his pocket

Tags: story-identification, movie

Does anyone know of a film where a boy lives in a post-apocalyptic future world in a caravan and has a duckling in his pocket? He travels through a desert.

Later in the film there's a robot in a chair with a screen behind him with a crown on the screen tilted and spinning round.

Comment: By caravan do you mean a traveling group of people and animals or some sort of mobile home?  Please be specific about each and every detail.